# C# OleDbParameter with Access DateTime query

Tags: c#, ms-access, datetime, oledbparameter

I have the following query that works from inside Access or from C# as an OleDbCommand:

```
SELECT Table1.ProductType, Sum(Table1.ProductsSold)
FROM Table1
WHERE (Table1.DateTime Between #5/16/2013# And #5/17/2013#)
GROUP BY Table1.ProductType;
```

Table1.DateTime is Date/Time data type.

Now I want to pass the dates as OleDbParameters.

```
SELECT Table1.ProductType, Sum(Table1.ProductsSold)
FROM Table1
WHERE (Table1.DateTime Between #@StartDate# And #@StopDate#)
GROUP BY Table1.ProductType;

cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@StartDate", OleDbType.Date));
cmd.Parameters["@StartDate"].Value = dateTimePicker1.Value.ToShortDateString();
cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@StopDate", OleDbType.Date));
cmd.Parameters["@StopDate"].Value = dateTimePicker2.Value.ToShortDateString();
```

I have searched and tried numerous things (VarChar and strings, single quotes instead of hashtags, hashtags in command or in parameter, etc.) without luck.  I want the dates to start at midnight (thus the ToShortDateString() and Date types.)

Answer (score 4):

You need to get rid of the hash mark (`#`) delimiters in the query text. Delimiters like `#` for dates and `'` for strings are required for *literal* SQL queries, but must be omitted in *parameterized* SQL queries. For reference, here is my working test code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data.OleDb;

namespace oledbTest1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var conn = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\__tmp\testData.accdb;");
            conn.Open();
            var cmd = new OleDbCommand(
                    "SELECT Table1.ProductType, SUM(Table1.ProductsSold) AS TotalSold " +
                    "FROM Table1 " +
                    "WHERE Table1.DateTime BETWEEN @StartDate AND @StopDate " +
                    "GROUP BY Table1.ProductType", 
                    conn);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StartDate", new DateTime(2013, 5, 16));
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StopDate", new DateTime(2013, 5, 17));
            OleDbDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            int rowCount = 0;
            while (rdr.Read())
            {
                rowCount++;
                Console.WriteLine("Row " + rowCount.ToString() + ":");
                for (int i = 0; i < rdr.FieldCount; i++)
                {
                    string colName = rdr.GetName(i);
                    Console.WriteLine("  " + colName + ": " + rdr[colName].ToString());
                }
            }
            rdr.Close();
            conn.Close();

            Console.WriteLine("Done.");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Note that I included distinct names for the parameters (to more closely match what you did), but remember that for Access OLEDB the parameter names are **ignored** and the parameters **must** be defined in exactly the same order that they appear in the command text.

### Edit

If you want to extract just the Date part of the DateTimePicker value then try something like this:

```
DateTime justTheDate = dateTimePicker1.Value.Date;
MessageBox.Show(justTheDate.ToString());
```

When I run that the MessageBox always displays something like `2013-05-01 00:00:00` (and not the current time).

Comment: My question might not have highlighted the problem.  My original parameters were similar to cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StartDate", dtpDailyStartDate.Value);  However, the DateTimePicker's Value property returned the correct Date, but the *CURRENT* time.

Comment: This led me to try this: cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StartDate", Convert.ToDateTime(dateTimePicker1.Value.ToShortDateString()));  This approach did not return any records.

Comment: The original parameter will work if I set the DateTimePicker's Format property to Short.  I had the DateTimePicker's Format set to Custom and the CustomeFormat property set to dddd, MMM dd, yyyy.  The Property window states this controls how the value is *displayed*.  It appears it also affects how the Value property is returned.  I would really like the weekday displayed but get the value with Midnight as the time.