# Querying Access 2007 DateTime with C#

Tags: c#, sql, datetime, ms-access-2007

I've just spent the last few hours trying do something which I thought would be very simple. I'm encountering a "Data type mismatch in criteria expression" error when I try to run a parameterized query with dates on an Access 2007 Database. The problem column in the Database is is of a "Date/Time" DataType.

In a simplified example -

`dataCommand.CommandText "SELECT * FROM tblData WHERE IDate > #24/07/2013 16:54:51#"`

This works. But as soon as I try to parametrize the date I encounter the error. So..

```
dataCommand.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM tblData WHERE IDate > @BackSearchDate"
....
dataCommand.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@BackSearchDate", backSearchDate))
```

Will encounter the error. I've tried to provide the backSearchDate variable in numerous ways. DateTime, strings of various formats etc do not work.

I found [this page](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/94377/oledbparameter-with-dbtype-datetime-throws-data-type-mismatch-in-criteria-expression#) which would indicate it's a known bug - but I've not been able to get any of the workarounds on the page to work either. I'm pretty stumped.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: When you are sending the parameter you are not encapsulating the date time in #DATETIME#, but if you are please share.

Comment: Also, just a shot in the dark, if you are putting the ## in the parameter, then maybe it is reading it as string?

Comment: Have you tried `dataCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BackSearchDate", backSearchDate)`?

Comment: @GordThompson I hadn't, but this results in the same error.

Answer (score 0):

So what I am saying is:

```
dataCommand.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM tblData WHERE IDate > @BackSearchDate"
```

**EDIT**

Checking out [Gord Thompson](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16622906/1504882)'s answer suggests that you should try:

```
var conn = new OleDbConnection(@"ConnString");
conn.Open();
var cmd = new OleDbCommand(
                "SELECT * FROM tblData WHERE IDate > @BackSearchDate", 
                conn);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BackSearchDate", new DateTime(backSearchDate));
OleDbDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

Comment: Hi Elias. Thanks for the reply. I'd read that #'s were not needed when the DateTime value was in a paramater, so I hadn't been doing that. I just tried the above and got a syntax error.

Comment: Okay, I wasn't sure if it would fail or not, sorry I can't be of more help. Good luck!

Comment: A bit late, but I am retrying to answer this question @user2598782

Answer (score 0):

To anyone encountering this problem in the future - It appears to work if you add the parameter in the following way:

```
DbParameter p = dataCommand.CreateParameter();
p.ParameterName = "@BackSearchDate";
p.Value = backSearchDate;
p.DbType = DbType.Date;
dataCommand.Parameters.Add(p);
```