# Access query with parameters works in Access, not in C#

Tags: c#, ms-access

I have a query that works in Access perfectly, but does not seem to work in C#.  I am pretty sure it is related to the parameters I am adding because if I hard code dates surrounded by '#' symbols then it works fine.  Does anyone know what could be the solution here?  Thanks Ahead

```
string queryAccessNewHires =
  @"SELECT cdate([Date of Hire]), Count([SSN]) AS DateCount 
    FROM [FED] 
    WHERE 
        IIf(
          IsNull([Date of Hire]), False, 
             IIf([Date of Hire] <> 'DoesNotApply' 
              AND [Date of Hire] <> ""
              AND CDate([Date of Hire]) > CDate(PBP)
              AND CDate([Date of Hire]) < CDate(PBE), True, False 
             )
        )
    GROUP BY [Date of Hire] 
    ORDER BY [Date of Hire]";

OleDbCommand cmdNewHires = new OleDbCommand(queryAccessNewHires, conn);
cmdNewHires.Parameters.AddWithValue("PBP", tbTYB.Text);
cmdNewHires.Parameters.AddWithValue("PBE", tbTYE.Text);
```

**EDIT::**
Thank you for the help.  Instead of receiving the "Syntax error in query expression" error, it seems to be understanding what I want when I change the code.  However the new error I am receiving is: "The OleDbParameterCollection only accepts non-null OleDbParameter type objects, not String objects"

```
string queryAccessNewHires = @"SELECT cdate([Date of Hire]), Count([SSN]) AS DateCount 
                               FROM [FED] 
                               WHERE IIf(IsNull([Date of Hire]),False, 
                                     IIf([Date of Hire]<>'DoesNotApply' 
                                     AND [Date of Hire]<>"" 
                                     AND CDate([Date of Hire])>CDate(?) 
                                     AND CDate([Date of Hire])<CDate(?), True, False))
                               GROUP BY [Date of Hire] 
                               ORDER BY [Date of Hire]";

OleDbCommand cmdNewHires = new OleDbCommand(queryAccessNewHires, conn);
cmdNewHires.Parameters.Add(tbTYB.Text);
cmdNewHires.Parameters.Add(tbTYE.Text);
```

**EDIT:**
Still no solution found.  I am thinking that I may have possibly made this harder than it needs to be so I want to show you guys the original query that I want to run from C#.  [Date of Hire] is a varchar and needs to be converted.  I cannot change the design.  This query returns "Invalid use of null."  I do not understand why this query does not execute.

```
SELECT cdate([Date of Hire]), Count([SSN]) AS DateCount 
                                        FROM [FED] 
                                        WHERE (CDate([Date of Hire]) > #1/1/2013# 
                                        AND CDate([Date of Hire]) < #12/31/2013#)
                                        GROUP BY [Date of Hire] 
                                        ORDER BY [Date of Hire]
```

Comment: By not working do you mean it throws an error or it returns no data?

Comment: I strongly believe that you cannot use the VBA stuff that works in Access inside your own application. I.e. `IIf`, `CDate`, `IsNull` etc.

Comment: @UweKeim IsNull, CDate and IIf are not 'VBA stuff' there are Jet/ACE stuff and work fine outside of MS Access.

Comment: Thanks, @Remou Are you sure? IIRC I tried code like above in the past without success. Great to hear though!

Comment: Have you looked at exactly what you have in PBP & PBE? This may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16621695/c-sharp-oledbparameter-with-access-datetime-query Do not forget that you are using CDate, so the query expects a string. Is that what you are supplying?

Comment: @UweKeim I have just tested with C# & ACE, although seeing I have been using some of this stuff in classic ASP, I really did not need to :)

Comment: @Remou I gave that solution a try, but I am still getting syntax errors with the query if I try and parameterize any other way than just using parameters.add

Comment: You have `AND [Date of Hire]<>""`, that should be `AND [Date of Hire]<>''`, however, it is quite unlikely that you will have an empty string in MS Access.

Comment: I removed it, you are right.

Comment: Even when I hardcode the date in.  It works in Access, but fails in C# saying data type mismatch in criteria expression.  It does not make any sense why an unaltered query fails in C# and not in Access to me.

Comment: BTW There is no need for GROUP BY and ORDER BY when both are the same field / column. GROUP BY will order by without any further fussing.

Comment: Thank you, I have removed it as well.

Comment: This is something else.  If I do not parameterize the query and leave it vulnerable to SQL injection it still does not run, but if I debug it and copy and paste that same query to access it runs just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Since you using `OleDb`, looks like you need to use `?` for your parameters. It doesn't support named parameters.

From [`OleDbCommand.Parameters` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.parameters%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> The OLE DB .NET Provider does not support named parameters for passing
>   parameters to an SQL statement or a stored procedure called by an
>   OleDbCommand when CommandType is set to Text. **In this case, the
>   question mark (?) placeholder must be used**. For example:
>
> SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE CustomerID = ?

```
AND CDate([Date of Hire]) > CDate(?)
AND CDate([Date of Hire]) < CDate(?), True, False
```

As Remou [said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22965568/access-query-with-parameters-works-in-access-not-in-c-sharp/22965639?noredirect=1#comment35066759_22965639);

> 'Does not support named parameters' just means that it will only
>   recognize a parameter by its position, not that you cannot use a name.
>   You do not have to use ?, you just have to ensure that the order is
>   correct.

Comment: Ah I see, I did not know that.  Thank you.  However, I am now receiving a different error.  "The OleDbParameter Collection only accepts non-null type objects, not string objects"

Comment: 'Does not support named parameters' just means that it will only recognize a parameter by its position, not that you cannot use a name.  You do not have to use ?, you just have to ensure that the order is correct. That quote is not quite correct.

Comment: @Remou You're right. Update my answer with your quote.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `?` as `OleDBCommand.Parameters` doesn't support named parameters.

[OleDbCommand.Parameters Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.parameters%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> The OLE DB .NET Provider does not support named parameters for passing
>   parameters to an SQL statement or a stored procedure called by an
>   OleDbCommand when CommandType is set to Text. In this case, the
>   question mark (?) placeholder must be used.
>
> Therefore, the order in which OleDbParameter objects are added to the
>   OleDbParameterCollection must directly correspond to the position of
>   the question mark placeholder for the parameter in the command text.

So your code would be like:

```
string queryAccessNewHires = @"SELECT cdate([Date of Hire]), Count([SSN]) AS DateCount 
    FROM [FED] 
    WHERE IIf(IsNull([Date of Hire]),False, IIf([Date of Hire]<>'DoesNotApply' AND [Date of Hire]<>"" AND CDate([Date of Hire])>CDate(?) AND CDate([Date of Hire])<CDate(?), True, False))
    GROUP BY [Date of Hire] 
    ORDER BY [Date of Hire]";

OleDbCommand cmdNewHires = new OleDbCommand(queryAccessNewHires, conn);
cmdNewHires.Parameters.Add(tbTYB.Text);
cmdNewHires.Parameters.Add(tbTYE.Text);
```

Comment: Thank you as well.  However, I am now getting a new error.  "The OleDbParameter Collection only accepts non-null type objects, not string objects"

Comment: I have commented on named parameters above.

Comment: @Remou, so any character(s) could be used instead of `?`, but only the order matters ? That is a very good point and I wans't aware of it. Certainly MSDN docs are misleading.

Comment: @Remou, but how does it differentiate between a parameter and other text in query ?

Comment: ? and @ symbols are the only ones that seem to trigger a parameter from my quick testing.

Comment: If the name is unknown, that is, it does not belong to a field / column in the sql, it is a parameter. Alternatively, you can state that it is a parameter at the beginning of the sql. From this, you can see that it is sensible to use a name that could not be a field.